# Phd computer science

Tags: thesis

I m glad to be here.
I m planning to start a phd in computer science, but i cant find a computer science field to fit my needs.
I am working on web applications and app applications over 7 years. I know php mysql jquery java javascript and asp. Furthermore i am working on setting up servers. 
My supervisor want some proposals as regard my phd subject.
I need a field that i can search new things and offer my services to the science.
Can you help me?

Comment: Nobody but yourself and your advisor can answer such a question. Further, "shopping"  questions are not allowed by the rules.

Comment: Yes, but the answers will depend on your personal preferences and the research field of your adviser. Random internet people will have no idea about any of that...

Answer (score 3):

These are a possible recommendation based on your experience. Again, such questions are considered shopping question here in academia.SE. Caution: This is not an optimal set of topics you might be interested in.

- Information retrieval (text, multimedia)
- Search Engine Optimisation
- Database ontology
- Information security over the web
- Data mining (This is a vast area, converge to something relevant)

Hope, this helps!